# on postback avoid iframe getting refreshed in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I have used iframe in my page.

For each and every postback event content of the iframe is getting refreshed.

I dont want to refresh content of iframe on eace postbackevent, iframe has to call only at time time of page load(!ispostback).

I have a big calculation in my iframe, so if it loads each and every time when parent page's(main page) postback event the it is no use of using iframe.

So please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

use updatepanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        content that only you want to postback
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

refrence http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Actually for each and every IsPostback event Iframe also getting refreshing. If i do any click event in my parent page this iframe should not get refresg. I don't want to refresh my page which is in IFrame.